# Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=syFDHFU2Sk6t0X6+IVqM8g==)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=syFDHFU2Sk6t0X6+IVqM8g==)

when i connected to sqldeveloper i got this error Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=syFDHFU2Sk6t0X6+IVqM8g==)